# Select Parent XML Elements based on Child element values LINQ C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, lambda

Having some difficulty filtering on a pretty large XML Document using LINQ.

Here is my XML (a portion of it)...

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XML-Schema-instance" version="1.2" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://weather.aero/schema/metar1_2.xsd">
  <request_index>54966812</request_index>
  <data_source name="metars" />
  <request type="retrieve" />
  <errors />
  <warnings />
  <time_taken_ms>3</time_taken_ms>
  <data num_results="6">
    <METAR>
      <raw_text>KDEN 131653Z 06007KT 9SM FEW080 SCT140 BKN250 09/01 A3025 RMK AO2 SLP238 T00940006</raw_text>
      <station_id>KDEN</station_id>
      <observation_time>2013-03-13T16:53:00Z</observation_time>
      <latitude>39.83</latitude>
      <longitude>-104.65</longitude>
      <temp_c>9.4</temp_c>
      <dewpoint_c>0.6</dewpoint_c>
      <wind_dir_degrees>60</wind_dir_degrees>
      <wind_speed_kt>7</wind_speed_kt>
      <visibility_statute_mi>9.0</visibility_statute_mi>
      <altim_in_hg>30.250984</altim_in_hg>
      <sea_level_pressure_mb>1023.8</sea_level_pressure_mb>
      <quality_control_flags>
        <auto_station>TRUE</auto_station>
      </quality_control_flags>
      <sky_condition sky_cover="FEW" cloud_base_ft_agl="8000" />
      <sky_condition sky_cover="SCT" cloud_base_ft_agl="14000" />
      <sky_condition sky_cover="BKN" cloud_base_ft_agl="25000" />
      <flight_category>VFR</flight_category>
      <metar_type>METAR</metar_type>
      <elevation_m>1640.0</elevation_m>
    </METAR>
    <METAR>
      <raw_text>KSEA 131653Z 20006KT 10SM FEW008 BKN070 OVC200 11/08 A3019 RMK AO2 SLP232 T01060083</raw_text>
      <station_id>KSEA</station_id>
      <observation_time>2013-03-13T16:53:00Z</observation_time>
      <latitude>47.45</latitude>
      <longitude>-122.32</longitude>
      <temp_c>10.6</temp_c>
      <dewpoint_c>8.3</dewpoint_c>
      <wind_dir_degrees>200</wind_dir_degrees>
      <wind_speed_kt>6</wind_speed_kt>
      <visibility_statute_mi>10.0</visibility_statute_mi>
      <altim_in_hg>30.188976</altim_in_hg>
      <sea_level_pressure_mb>1023.2</sea_level_pressure_mb>
      <quality_control_flags>
        <auto_station>TRUE</auto_station>
      </quality_control_flags>
      <sky_condition sky_cover="FEW" cloud_base_ft_agl="800" />
      <sky_condition sky_cover="BKN" cloud_base_ft_agl="7000" />
      <sky_condition sky_cover="OVC" cloud_base_ft_agl="20000" />
      <flight_category>VFR</flight_category>
      <metar_type>METAR</metar_type>
      <elevation_m>136.0</elevation_m>
    </METAR>
```

What I am trying to do is get all of the METAR elements that fall within a range for latitude and longitude.  For example:

Latitude > 52 && < 55
Longitude < -121 && > -123

The idea is to capture the METARs for a given area.

Here is my code:

```
     double southLat = 52.09;
     double northLat = 53.95;
     double westLong = -123.17;
     double eastLong = -121.87;

     XDocument response = XDocument.Load("file");

     var metars = response.Descendants("METAR")
        .Where
        (l => l.Element("latitude") != null || l.Element("longitude") != null
        && (Double)l.Element("latitude") >= southLat 
        && (Double)l.Element("latitude") <= northLat
        && (Double)l.Element("longitude") >= westLong
        && (Double)l.Element("longitude") <= eastLong
   );
```

I managed to get the first part working (exclude elements that have null latitude or longitude values....however I still get METARs that are outside of the bounds I would like.

Any suggestions?

Comment: l => l.Element("latitude") != null || l.Element("longitude") != null. Change the || to &&.

Comment: That did it.  I'm confused as to why...I thought the the !=null was excluding any METAR that didn't have Lat OR Long...given that - I wanted the resulting items to be filtered on the criteria specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @roughnex said in the comments, the following line:

```
l.Element("latitude") != null || l.Element("longitude") != null
```

needs to be changed to:

```
l.Element("latitude") != null && l.Element("longitude") != null
```

The reason for this is [how boolean logic works](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra).

In your code, you have the following conditional statement:

```
l.Element("latitude") != null || l.Element("longitude") != null
&& (Double)l.Element("latitude") >= southLat 
&& (Double)l.Element("latitude") <= northLat
&& (Double)l.Element("longitude") >= westLong
&& (Double)l.Element("longitude") <= eastLong
```

but let's cut out the details and make it simpler where each letter is a condition:

```
A || B && C && D && F
```

When it's reduced to simpler terms, it is easier to see that if `A` resolves to `True`, then the rest of the conditional is ignored. That is why you were getting results that were outside of your desired area, because their latitude wasn't null.

Comment: That absolutely makes sense.  I don't proclaim to be good at this (clearly).  However - I never really encountered a logical error such as what I had.  I was under the impression that all conditions must be met - not just the first one that encounters to true.  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, this is a programming concept called short-circuiting. In boolean logic, if you have a condition

```
A || B
```

and A evaluates to true, then B won't be evaluated because the expression (A || B) will be true regardless of B's value. Similarly, if

```
A && B
```

and A evaluates to false, then B is not evaluated because the entire expression will evaluate to false, regardless of B's value. (False && true will always be false.)

Alternatively, if

```
A || B
```

and A is false, then B *must* be evaluated, because in an OR comparison, only one has to be true for the whole expression to be true (False || True will be True). So since A is false, there's still a chance that B could be true, so we have to check.